# remove the sparse text from the edge of an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a scanned image which has some text (the two `B`s) from the edge (left or right side of the image) I'd like to remove.

[image: scanned image]
Below is the code I have tried:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Load the image

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Apply thresholding to obtain a binary image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Use connectedComponentsWithStats to get the objects' properties
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity=8)

# Remove small objects
for i in range(1, num_labels):
    x = stats[i][0]
    w = stats[i][2]
    if x < 50 and w < 50 and labels[stats[i][1], stats[i][2]] != 0:
        labels[labels == i] = 0

# Convert the labels image to 8-bit unsigned integer
labels = labels.astype('uint8')

# Apply connected component analysis again to update the labels
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(labels, connectivity=8)
cv2.imwrite("output_image.png", labels*255/num_labels)
```

But this created a black-background image, the edge text is not removed either.

Additionally, this is the image with sparse text on the right edge side: The grammar info on the right should all be removed as the `B`s are on the first image.

[image: sparse text on the right edge side]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the left side labels, and appling connected component analysis again, we may fill the left side connected components in `img` with white color.

Replace `labels[labels == i] = 0` with:

```
img[labels == i] = 255
```

Write `img` as output:  `cv2.imwrite("output_image.png", img)`.

---

There is an issue in the statement: `labels[stats[i][1], stats[i][2]] != 0`.
`[i][1]` is equivalent to `[i][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]` (it's OK).
`stats[i][2]` is equivalent to `[i][cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]` (this is an issue).
Replace `labels[stats[i][1], stats[i][2]] != 0` with:

```
labels[stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP], stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]] != 0
```

Note:
The above condition is redundant, and can be removed, because all `labels` (starting from `i` = `1`) are greater than zero.

---

For improving the result, we may dilate `thresh` a little - required for removing the gray "thread" that surrounds the B letters.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
   
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Load the image

# Apply thresholding to obtain a binary image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))  # Dilate thresh because the B letters has a gray "halo".

# Use connectedComponentsWithStats to get the objects' properties
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity=8)

# Remove small objects
for i in range(1, num_labels):
    x = stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
    w = stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]

    #if x < 50 and w < 50 and labels[stats[i][1], stats[i][2]] != 0:
    if x < 50 and w < 50:  # and labels[stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP], stats[i][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]] != 0:
        # labels[labels == i] = 0
        img[labels == i] = 255  # Fill img with white color were labels == i

# Convert the labels image to 8-bit unsigned integer
#labels = labels.astype('uint8')

# Apply connected component analysis again to update the labels
#num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(labels, connectivity=8)
#cv2.imwrite("output_image.png", labels*255/num_labels)
cv2.imwrite("output_image.png", img)
```

---

Output:
[image]

---

Notes:

- The original image has a black column that goes from top to bottom.
  That black column is also removed.
- There is a tiny leftover of the B letters - we may have to dilate `thresh` with a larger kernel.
- In the posted sample image, we may simply fill the entire left side of the image with white color (without searching for connected components):
  `img[:, 0:50] = 255`

---

Update: Finding the size of the margins.

There are multiple approaches for finding the size of the margins.
The approaches are heuristical, and are not guaranteed to work in all cases.

One approach is based on the assumption that the text is "thinner" in the margins.
We may sum all the columns, and decide which part is the margin according to the sums.

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("2.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Downscale image in the horizontal axis - each column of resized_img is 1% of the total width
resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (100, img.shape[0]), cv2.INTER_AREA)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(resized_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
sum_of_rows = np.sum(thresh==255, axis=0)  # Sum the rows of thresh (use thresh==255 for converting 255 to 1).

plt.figure()
plt.plot(sum_of_rows)
plt.show()
```

Plot:
[image]

We may look for the gap (where sum is zero).
We may look for continuous portions where the sums are below some threshold (the threshold may be relative to the median of the sums for example).

I am sure you can find a third example where the heuristics fails.
Finding a robust solution may be challenging...

Comment: Thanks. @Rotem I wonder if there is a more general way to determine if the sparse text is on the edge of the image than using the magic number `50` or other magic numbers in the code? Because the left and right side of the image could vary in width (Please refer to the second image I have updated in the post).

Comment: There are many options. I updated my answer with an example.